# How to change the name of the Columnheaders in a UNION statement

Tags: sql, union, column-alias

The Column headers in a UNION query are named as the select statement of the first query, how can I change the column headers to `Entities` and `Errors`?

```
The Query is:

SELECT DISTINCT '1001account' AS [1001account]
    ,[1001account] AS '1001account'
FROM XXX
WHERE StresstestaccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%'
    AND BalancesheetAmount <> 0
    AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [1001account]) > 0
    OR [1001account] IS NULL

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT '[MAX(InterestRate)]' AS InterestType
    ,MAX(InterestRate) AS 'MAXInterestRate'
FROM XXX
WHERE BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
    AND StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE 'Yes'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT '[MIN(InterestRate)]' AS InterestType
    ,MIN(InterestRate) AS 'MINInterestRate'
FROM XXX
WHERE BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
    AND StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE 'Yes'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT '[MAX(SwapRate)]' AS [SwapRate]
    ,MAX(SwapRate) AS 'MAXSwapRate'
FROM XXX
WHERE BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
    AND StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE 'Yes'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT '[MIN(SwapRate)]' AS [SwapRate]
    ,MIN(SwapRate) AS 'MINSwapRate'
FROM XXX
WHERE BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
    AND StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE 'Yes'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT '[MAX([Margin])]' AS [Margin]
    ,MAX([Margin]) AS 'MAXS[Margin]'
FROM XXX
WHERE BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
    AND StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE 'Yes'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT '[MIN([Margin])]' AS [Margin]
    ,MIN([Margin]) AS 'MIN[Margin]'
FROM XXX
WHERE BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
    AND StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE 'Yes'
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
**1001account**         **1001account**
[MAX([Margin])]         170.8372200000
[MAX(InterestRate)]         172.7691400000
[MAX(SwapRate)]         70.8750000000
[MIN([Margin])]         -70.6084500000
[MIN(InterestRate)]         -19.4163150000
[MIN(SwapRate)]         -1.0392500000
1001account                 NULL
5028account                 NULL
```

As you can see the column headers refer to the select statement of the first query. How can I change the name of these headers while using a `UNION` statement?

Comment: Put column aliases in the first SELECT.

Comment: you already wrote what should be done.

Comment: There are probably better ways to write this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the alias in the first select

```
SELECT DISTINCT '1001account' AS Entities
    ,[1001account] AS Errors
FROM XXX
WHERE StresstestaccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%'
    AND BalancesheetAmount <> 0
    AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [1001account]) > 0
    OR [1001account] IS NULL
```